# what is the error in my sorting algorithm?

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to make a sorting algorithm using python, but I am encountering a problem and I can't figure it out. I'll paste my code below.

basic function:

- gets an array of numbers
- goes through and checks if a number is bigger than the next one
- if it is, swap it and set a variable to tell the function to run again
  at the end the numbers should be in ascending order

```
mainArr = [5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4]
def sort():
  sorted = True
  tempVal = 0
  for x in range(0, mainArr.len - 1):
    if mainArr[x] > mainArr[x+1]:
      sorted = False
      tempVal = mainArr[x]
      mainArr[x] = mainArr[x+1]
      mainArr[x+1] = tempVal
      sorted = False
  print(mainArr)
  if not sorted:
    sort()
print("\n\n")
print(mainArr)
```

I have checked the code, but I think it needs a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please change your `sorted` variable to something different since it's a built-in keyword in Python

Comment: Also, is there a particular error? Usually sorting algorithms don't run in one `for` loop but rather iterate continuously until the iterable is sorted

Comment: Please could you paste the specific error you are getting into your question?

Comment: Your code never calls the `sort()` function, which is why it's not doing anything (including raising an error).  Once you actually call the function you'll hit the error that @James_481 pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to actually call your `sort()` function:

```
print(mainArr)  # print the unsorted list
print()
sort()          # sort the list
print()
print(mainArr)  # print the sorted list
```

This gets you an error:

```
    for x in range(0, mainArr.len - 1):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'
```

which is because, indeed, a list does not have a `len` property.  You want to change `mainArr.len` to `len(mainArr)`.

That then gets you the output:

```
[5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4]

[2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

All the output in the middle is emitted by `sort()` itself as it recurses.

It looks like with that fix, your `sort` function works, but here are a few simple fixes/suggestions:

- `sorted` is a built-in function, so it's not recommended to use that name for another variable.
- You don't need the`tempVal` thing in Python to swap two values; just do a tuple assignment!
- If your function takes the list as an argument, it can sort any list, not just `mainArr`.

With those fixes the code looks like:

```
mainArr = [5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4]

def sort(arr):
    """Sort the input list 'arr' in-place."""
    is_sorted = True
    for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
        if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
            is_sorted = False
            arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
    if not is_sorted:
        sort(arr)

print(mainArr)
sort(mainArr)
print(mainArr)
```

I'd also suggest not using recursion (Python doesn't do tail-call optimization by default, so you should avoid using recursion when it's easy to do the same thing with a loop).  Using a `while` loop outside your `for` loop you'd have something like:

```
def sort(arr):
    """Sort the input list 'arr' in-place."""
    keep_sorting = True
    while keep_sorting:
        keep_sorting = False
        for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
            if arr[i] > arr[i+1]:
                arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
                keep_sorting = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the specific error message in your question so it's hard to understand what's wrong, but one thing I noticed was that you have written:

`mainArr.len`.

This doesn't work in python. Len is a function that takes an array as a parameter. You would have to write this:

`len(mainArr)`

Comment: np, if this is the solution please accept it as the answer so other people coming to this question see that this is the correct answer